# Rails: RSpec: using global path variables only seems to work within "it" blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

While following Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, I was experimenting with some custom functions in my test section, and ran into a restriction that surprised me. Basically, global path variables (eg "root_path") only work within the "do...end" block of an "it" section within a "describe" block of the RSpec tests.

I believe the following details boil down to the question, what is special about the "it" block which enabled "root_path" to work there while not working outside of the "it" block?

(I've determined a workaround, but I'm curious whether there's a solid explanation of this behavior.)

**File:** spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

**This fails:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

def check_stable(path)
  it "should be stable" do
    get path
    response.status.should be(200)
  end
end

describe "StaticPages" do
  describe "Home => GET" do
    check_stable(root_path)
  end
end
```

**This succeeds:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "StaticPages" do
  describe "Home => GET" do
    it "should be stable" do
      get root_path
      response.status.should be(200)
    end
  end
end
```

The failure is basically:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
Exception encountered: #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<Class:0x00000004cecd78>>
```

... any idea why?

I tried all of the suggestions on these two threads:

[Hartl's Tutorial Section 5.3.2: Rails Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752340/hartls-tutorial-section-5-3-2-rails-routes)

[Rspec and named routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475857/rspec-and-named-routes)

None worked until I sussed out the issue above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, named routes work only within `it` or `specify` blocks. But it's easy to modify the code:

```
def should_be_stable(path)
  get path
  response.status.should be(200)
end

describe "StaticPages" do
  describe "Home => GET" do
    it { should_be_stable(root_path) }
  end
end
```

You steel need [to include url_helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475857/rspec-and-named-routes)

Comment: ... or within `before :each do` or `after each do` blocks.

Comment: Fair point re: ease of modification -- and I appreciate you demonstrating the tweak while still maintaining the one-liner test from the "describe". Keeps the sub-functions slimmer as well, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

`it` blocks (or `specify` blocks) are what denote actual tests. Inside a test, you will have access to the full complement of Rails and Rspec helpers; outside the test, not so much (as you have worked out).